# App Engine's filter vs. gql methods

Tags: google-app-engine, filter, gql, gqlquery

I have a user in my system who has created an entity which I'd like to retrieve. I'm attempting to do this using a [filter](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_filter) because it's supposed to be faster than a call to the [*gql* method](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass.html). However, the filter returns no results and *gql* works.

```
randy_res = Vote.all().filter('created_by=', randy).fetch(limit=10)
randy_res = Vote.gql('WHERE created_by=:1', randy)
```

Is there any reason why  the *filter* would return an empty list and the *gql* call would return the proper results?

Comment: As an aside, the speed difference between using gql and filters to build the query should be extremely trivial compared to the overhead of actually executing the query. If gql is more readable or more intuitive for you, stick with it.

Comment: As much as I dislike GQL, @Drew is right: Any performance difference is trivial.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using `filter()`, you are *required* to have a space between the field name and the operator.  To get your `filter()` call to work as intended, you just need to insert a space before the equal sign:

```
randy_res = Vote.all().filter('created_by =', randy).fetch(limit=10)
```

Comment: ahhhhhh!  this made me go insane for a night.  Silent failures are my worst nightmare.  I filed an issue 2 years ago, but it doesn't look like anyone else cares (only 6 stars).
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=688

Comment: @Peter Unfortunately, it's not a bug: The original code is a perfectly valid query for the property with name 'created_by=', and any change would break this (admittedly fairly uncommon) behaviour.

Comment: sigh.  I know it's not a bug in the strict sense. I do like calling it a "wart" in the api, as ryanb put it in the issues log. :)  Maybe I should look into creating a rule in findbugs or eclipse that would give me a warning when it sees the lack of a space.

Comment: Agreed. It might be helpful to highlight this behavior in the docs.  The docs always use a space before the operator, but I don't remember seeing any tips highlighting the importance of this space.

Comment: this made me go crazy too, yesterday. But @nick's explanation is reasonable